# Redirect all my blogspot link to my new wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, redirect, blogspot

I have one old blog using blogspot http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/ .On many places have shared my blog links. Now i have launched my new blog using wordpress [startcoding.in](http://startcoding.in/) .

Thing I want to do is how I can redirect all my blogspot link to this new wordpress blog without any loss of data.

Have already exported XML data file by login blogspot **-->** Setting **-->** Other **-->** Export Blog.  This gives XML data format file, which i import in wordpress.

Doing this all my post are imported sucessfully thought some googleplus comments are missed now i need to transfer all blogspot link to my new blog

Answer (score 1):

In the case of only wanting to redirect certain posts or pages all you have to do is use the form of `Redirect 301 / http://startcoding.in/`
though where the "/" is just write the page on your old site and where http://startcoding.in/ is just write the website then the page you want it to redirect to.
for example if you wanted to redirect "satindersinght.blogspot.in/my_page" to "startcoding.in/my_new_page" all you would have to do is:
`Redirect 301 /my_page http://startcoding.in/my_new_page`